# How can I rearrange name formats in Textpad using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, replace, textpad

In Textpad I have opened a TXT that was exported from a spread sheet. It's a very, very long list of names formatted as "Last, First".

How can I very quickly do a Find-and-Replace to make them all "First Last"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If delimited properly, with line breaks between names, and no additional commas are in the Last or First names, then you should be able to import this into an excel file. From there you can edit the file with much greater ease.

Steps, open text file with Microsoft Excel, (use comma delimited), saved it as an excel file, made a third column with the following formula

```
=CONCATENATE(B1," ",A1)
```

[Fill this down to replicate this formula](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/tipsandfaqs/qt/81130filldown.htm)

Lastly, delete Column B and C, and resave the file as a text file.